# I cannot apply CSS in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I cannot apply the CSS in the table. For example I want the table to be displayed in the middle and to change the font color and size as well. But I can't. Should I use the `tbody` tag since I have the `body` one? Also I generate the table data from database.

```
    <?php 

      include 'connect.php';

      $year = $_POST['year']; 
      $lecturer = $_POST['lecturer']; 
      $years     = array(
          2005,
          2006,
          2007
      );
     $lecturers = array(
         'lec1',
         'lec2',
         'lec3',
         'lec4'
      );

    if (in_array($lecturer, $lecturers) && in_array($year, $years)) {

           $sql = "SELECT unit_name,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $lecturer WHERE year=$year";

           $result = mysql_query($sql);
     }

    else {
         echo "No data found";
    }
?>
     <html>   
      <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
      </head>
       <body>
         <div id="mytable">
           <table width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">
               <tr>
                 <tbody>
                  <td>Unit Name</td>
                  <td>A1 </td>
                  <td>A2 </td>
                  <td>A3 </td>
                  <td>L1 </td>
                  <td>L2 </td>
                  <td>R1 </td>
                  <td>R2 </td>
                  <td>U1 </td>
                  <td>U2 </td>
                  <td>U3 </td>
        </tbody>
      </tr>

  <?php
       while($unit=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['unit_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u3']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
       }
   ?>
   </table>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>


css:


      <!-- principalLecturers
     -->
      #body{
        color:white;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
       }
      #table{
        margin:0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        color:#b50a1e;
        font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:10px;
       }  
       #table#mytable{
         display: table-row-group;
         vertical-align: middle;
         border-color: inherit
       }
```

Comment: The correct hierarchy is `table` -> `tbody` -> `tr` -> `th/td`, You've got `tr` and `tbody` reversed. Also, `#body` and `#table` are looking for elements with the id's `body` and `table`. If you want to match an element type, remove the `#` in CSS.

Comment: `#table#mytable` - wow... This one just cannot work by definiton: element cannot have two ids at once

Comment: Where is the id of table given? `#table`

Comment: You don't seem to understand CSS selectors quite right. See [Type selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#type-selectors), [ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anywhere in your table `<table id="table"...>`. That's why the styles for `#table {...}` does not apply.